# name of List field gets truncated when mapping to record

Tags: java, record, mapstruct, mapper

I have an issue where field names get truncated when:
the field has an generic type (I tried List<>, Set<> and I am suspecting that custom types should fail as well) the target is a java record

To reproduce create ClassA and ClassB like this:

```
public class ClassA {

    private String someString;
    private List<String> stringList;

    public String getSomeString() { return someString; }
    public void setSomeString(String someString) { this.someString = someString; }
    public List<String> getStringList() { return stringList; }
    public void setStringList(List<String> stringList) { this.stringList = stringList; }

}
```

```
public record ClassB(
    String someString,
    List<String> stringList
) {};
```

Then create the following mapper:

```
@Mapper
public interface ABMapper {
  ClassA bToA(ClassB classB);
  ClassB aToB(ClassA classA);
}
```

You'll get a compiler error (pointing to the aToB function) that says: Unmapped target property: "ingList".
Obviously the first 3 letters of "stringList" have been dropped when mapping into a record.

I expect the correct result.

Comment: What version of mapstruct are you using?

Answer (score 0):

**The issue:**

I have the same issue, based on its [Github](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct) source code, Mapstruct uses setters and getters for collections to find property name and remove 3 first characters to find property name.

**Solutions:**

1. Write a custom mapper in an abstract class mapper
2. Put a getter method for your collection in java record